# django manytomany - get value from through

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a manytomany field between 2 models:

```
class userProfile(models.Model):
    boughtCoupons = models.ManyToManyField(Coupon, through='UserCoupons')

class Coupon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class UserCoupons(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(userProfile)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Now my problem is:

Given a coupon and a user ID, how can I get the date in which the user bought the coupon ?
Something like `mycoupon.boutcoupons.filter(user=userid)`  and then get the date somehow..

Problem is that the field belongs to the user... and if I access the field from the user I get a list of coupons anyway, without the date.

I just need the coupon-userID .date value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just query UserCoupons directly.

```
UserCoupons.objects.get(user=myuser, coupon=mycoupon)
```

or use the reverse relation from Coupon:

```
mycoupon.usercoupon_set.get(user=myuser)
```

**Edit in response to comment** There are two separate things going on here. Firstly, a ManyToMany *does* get added to the other side as a set (actually, a Manager) - using the name of the source model plus `_set`. So in this case, `Coupon` will have a `userprofile_set` attribute.

Secondly, however, you'll see that's not what I used in my answer. That's because ForeignKeys also add reverse relation Managers to their target models. Your through model defines ForeignKeys to both userProfile and Coupon, so they both get `usercoupons_set` attributes.

Comment: ah ok, so if I create a manytomany field in one model, it gets added automatically to the other as a set ? But with what name ? the field name or "through" class name ?

Comment: first in your answer you say ```mycoupon.usercoupon_set.get``` whereas i think is ```mycoupon.usercoupons_set.get``` with an ```s```. 

Secondly i would like to answer, what if i wanted to access ```usercoupons_set``` through i ```UserProfile``` instance? Is that doable ?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention a point here. I know the question has already been answered by Daniel:

You can access the "date" attribute in the through the table using below code:

```
mycoupon.boutcoupons.filter(usercoupons__date="***")
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is quite old however I am posting a easiest and straight answer to such problems as I myself struggled a lot in order to solve this issue and found no help from internet, so posting it to help many like me.

```
Models.py
------------------------
class userProfile(models.Model):
    boughtCoupons = models.ManyToManyField(Coupon, through='UserCoupons')

class UserCoupons(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(userProfile)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
    date = models.DateField()


class Coupon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

View.py
-----------------
def result(request):
    a = userProfile.objects.all()
    b = Coupon.objects.all(name=a.boughtCoupons.all.0)
    c = UserCoupons.objects.all(coupon=c.name.all.0)
    context = {'a':a,'b':b,'c':c}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)

 intex.html
 --------------------
 *your Html declaration 
 * content
 {%for dtl in c%}
 <table>
<tr>
<th>coupon</th>
<th>UserID</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>{{c.coupon}}</td>
<td>{{c.user}}</td>
<td>{{c.date}}</td>
</tr>
    </table>
```